# Balancing Deen & Dunya

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

I pray 5x a day, and I try my very hardest to pray on time, I also make dua and dhikr after prayer, and read adkhaar daily.
But when I'm not doing this, I don't have a job (in shaa allah Allah will grant me one) and my school schedule is very light, so I usually just sleep and watch tv shows. 
Is this bad or okay?

Comment: Physical exercise is good for keeping healthy...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to balancing Deen and Dunya (religion and real-life). Sleep and watch TV shows is not productive activities, so you should struggling to get some jobs. It also important to note, that Dunya, is not only about work. But also social relation between human to people.

I remember that there is a hadith told that moslem people should keep their relation to other people, as good as their relation to Allah.

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Comment: "as good as their relation to Allah" citation needed